# Unable to boot into ubuntu 13.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

My pc has ubuntu 13.04 alongside window 8. Last time I used my pc (in ubuntu) is 5 days ago and it was fine. Today I tried to boot into ubuntu but failed. Normal boot seems to stuck forever at the purple ubuntu screen with nothing on it. I also tried to select recovery mode in grub screen. What happened is the screen(command line) was flooded by this line

> udevd[360]: timeout: killing '/sbin/modprobe -bv pci:v000010DEd00000DC4sv000010DEsd0000085ABc03sc00i00' [339]

I also tried to run boot-repair in live-USB. Nothings worked. This is the paste log from the boot-repair.  >> http://paste.ubuntu.com/6133079/

Window 8 is still working. Any help is very appreciated. Also this is my first time posting on this I dunno what I need to tell.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need a GPT partition to dual boot in windows 8. I changed mine back to NTFS and it won't boot into Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: I think I haven't changed anything about its format (at least intentionally) and duel-boot even worked 5 days ago. Anyway, thank you for suggestion !.